# Calculating integral with integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

I need to calculate
$$
\int_0^t s^{-\frac{1}{a}}(t-s)^{\frac{1}{2a}-1} \ ds=c_a t^{-\frac{1}{2a}},
$$
but I don't know how to approach it. I tried integration by parts, which didn't yield much but some term like $\int_0^t s^{\frac{1}{a}-1}(t-s)^{\frac{1}{2a}} \ ds$ multiplied by a constant. Trying to calculate this wasn't much easier.

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: You are missing a $ds$.

Comment: Integration by parts is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $s=pt$, $$\int_0^t s^{-1/a}(t-s)^{1/2a-1}ds=\int_0^1 (pt)^{-1/a}(t-pt)^{1/2a-1}d(pt)$$

> $$=t^{-1/2a}\int_0^1 p^{-1/a}(1-p)^{1/2a-1}dp.$$